# can we have a non primary key as partition key in azure cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating a Collection in cosmos db which can exceed 10GB. The collection does not have any primary key. is it good idea to make the  non primary key  field which i will be querying frequently as the partition key?

Answer (score 0):

> is it good idea to make the non primary key field which i will be
>   querying frequently as the partition key?

Actually, the choice of partition key is a question that deserves to be weighed repeatedly. The best partition key is one that provides for even distribution and higher cardinality.

Since choosing to be the non primary key that you will query frequently is your option now, I just discuss some of the possible positive and negative things as your references.

Firstly, we could say that the primary key is the safest and probably, most appropriate choice for a partition key.

It guarantees uniqueness of the value, which other than unique keys, is the only way to achieve. The distribution will be even and because the primary key will be your partition key, you will be able to use it in order to retrieve the document by reading it, instead of querying, which reduces operation speed and cost.

In terms of performance, if your query frequently field is not partition key, your query will definitely reduce query performance by crossing partitions. Surely, if the amount of data is large, it will have much effect.

In terms of cost, cosmos db is charged primarily by storage space and RUs consumption. As you said, choosing non primary key as partition key will lead less indexes storage. If mostly queries are not cross-partition, it also saves RUs consumption.

In terms of using of stored procedure, triggers or UDF, you can't use cross-partition transactions via stored procedures and triggers. Because then are partitioned so that you need to specify the partition key(cardinality is only 1) when you use them.

Just note that if partition key is created, it cannot be deleted or modified later. So consider it before you choose and make sure you do the data backup.

More details, still refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data).